# Configuring antdesign using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am using this [react redux starter](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit). I want to use this starter with 
[ant design](https://ant.design). But I am having a hard time to add ant design to this starter via webpack.
From the ant design doc I am suppose to use a .babelrc file to import the ant design babel library into my project. The starter doesn't use a .babelrc file to load babel plugins (as shown [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce#Use-modularized-antd)), it uses the [webpack configuration file](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/master/build/webpack.config.js).

How do I add the ant design library (the code below) into the webpack configuration file?

```
{
 "plugins": [
  ["import", { libraryName: "antd", style: "css" }] // `style: true` for less]
}
```

**NB:** I already tried the approach in the ant design doc, but I get an error message:  `Unknown plugin "import" in *\.babelrc at 0`. I also tried inserted a line `["import", { libraryName: "antd", style: "css" }]` into row 76 the webpack config [file](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/master/build/webpack.config.js) of the starter, but error `Unknonw plugin "import" specified in base at 4`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [babel-plugin-import](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import).

```
npm i babel-plugin-import --save-dev
yarn add babel-plugin-import --dev
```

An example of webpack config for "JSX" is shown below:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: [nodeModulesDir],
    options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        plugins: [
            'transform-decorators-legacy',
            'add-module-exports',
            ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": true }],
            ["react-transform", {
                transforms: [
                    {
                        transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
                        imports: ['react'],
                        locals: ['module']
                    }
                ]
            }]
        ],
        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
    }
},
```

The JSX files are loaded using babel-loader. babel-loader runs the plugins. One of the plugin is babel-plugin-import. This plugin ensures that antd is partially imported. `import { Checkbox } from 'antd';` is converted to `var Checkbox = require('antd/lib/checkbox');` by the plugin.

Comment: I already have it install. How do I import the antdesign babel library into the webpack configuration file, and not the .babelrc?